# Вставка и обновление значений в с помощью peewee

Tags: python, база-данных, sqlite, peewee

Задача:
принимать данные от tg бота и вставлять их в бд sqlite. То есть пользователь написал имя, бот вставил имя в таблицу по message_chat_id, потом юзер отошёл на пять минут, вернулся добавил ещё город и тд.

Проблема:
Ставлял данные так `User.insert(message_chat_id=id, city=data).on_conflict_replace().execute()`, заменяя лишь название поля (в данной случае city).

При получении всех данных по пользователю, оказывалось, что базе есть лишь message_chat_id И последнее вставленное поле.

При чтении документации и ответов на stackoverflow мне сообщили, что нужно вставлять вот так:
`User.insert(message_chat_id=id, name=data) .on_conflict(conflict_target=[User.message_chat_id], preserve=[User.message_chat_id, User.city, User.phone, User.mail, User.platform_type], update={User.name: data}) .execute()`

А если быть точнее там вставка происходит всей записи в таблице по всем столбцам, а у меня только два столбца (message_chat_id, в зависимости от ситуации), на что я при попытке добавить в массив preserve (с англ сохранять) все столбцы, чьи данные менять не нужно, получаю полную красных записей консоль

[image: Структура модели]

Метод, который добавляет данные в таблицу:

```
def insertOrUpdate(id, typePlace, data):
if typePlace == 'name':
    User.insert(message_chat_id=id, name=data, city=None, phone=None, mail=None, platform_type=None).on_conflict(
        conflict_target=[User.message_chat_id], preserve=[User.city, User.phone, User.mail, User.platform_type],
        update={User.name: data}).execute()
elif typePlace == 'city':
    pass
    User.insert(message_chat_id=id, city=data).on_conflict_replace().execute()
elif typePlace == 'phone':
    pass
    User.insert(message_chat_id=id, phone=data).on_conflict_replace().execute()
elif typePlace == 'mail':
    pass
    User.insert(message_chat_id=id, mail=data).on_conflict_replace().execute()
elif typePlace == 'pt':
    pass
    User.insert(message_chat_id=id, platform_type=data).on_conflict_replace().execute()
else:
    print("Ошибка, нету такого типа:", typePlace)
```

Comment: Для начала создай таблицу users

Comment: @SergeySemkin оу спасибо. но проблема вставки данный ещё актуальна

Comment: Но ошибка должна быть уже другая

Comment: @shizik123 Отправьте пожалуйста код метода

Comment: @SergeySemkin pastebin.com/d52ehuTQ

Comment: @shizik123 Исправьте описание вопроса добавив код из ссылки

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Отредактировал ваш метод. conflict_target нужен, чтобы сохранить данные передаваемые в запросе, а не в базе. Если вы используете только id и name к примеру, то остальное не нужно перечислять со значением None, и соответственно conflict_target Тоже не нужен.

```
def insertOrUpdate(id, typePlace, data):
if typePlace == 'name':
    User.insert(message_chat_id=id, name=data)\
        .on_conflict(
        conflict_target=[User.message_chat_id],
        update={User.name: data})\
        .execute()
elif typePlace == 'city':
    User.insert(message_chat_id=id, city=data )\
        .on_conflict(
            conflict_target=[User.message_chat_id],
            update={User.city: data})\
        .execute()
elif typePlace == 'phone':
    User.insert(message_chat_id=id, phone=data)\
        .on_conflict(
            conflict_target=[User.message_chat_id],
            update={User.phone: data})\
        .execute()
elif typePlace == 'mail':
    User.insert(message_chat_id=id, mail=data)\
        .on_conflict(
            conflict_target=[User.message_chat_id],
            update={User.mail: data})\
        .execute()
elif typePlace == 'pt':
    User.insert(message_chat_id=id, platform_type=data)\
        .on_conflict(
            conflict_target=[User.message_chat_id],
            update={User.platform_type: data})\
        .execute()
else:
    print("Ошибка, нету такого типа:", typePlace)
```